# Is there a warning free template function to convert basic types to string

Tags: c++, templates, ambiguous

I want to provide a templated function that converts most basic types to string.
The best I have come up with so far is the following:

```
template<typename T> inline std::string anyToString(const T& var) {
  std::ostringstream o;
  o << var;
  return o.str();
}
```

The function can e.g. be used for the following:

```
 class TimeError:public std::runtime_error{
     public:
       explicit TimeError(int time):std::runtime_error(anyToString(time)),
       mTime(time){};
     protected:
       int mTime;
     };
```

The problem with anyToString and similar functions is the generation of ambiguity warnings when compiling with gcc version 4.4.3 -Wall -Wexta -Werror
`"ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second`"

To my knowledge the reason for the warning lies in the implicit conversion possibilities when calling <<.

Those ambiguities are mainly generated by other templates as the following:

```
  template<typename T>
    T& operator<<(T& out, const SymRad& angle){
    return out << angle.deg();
  }
```

But those have other advantages like working for several stream types.
So I would like to keep them. If I turn the second template into a plain method for e.g. ostream the ambiguity is cleaned, but I'm looking for sth. that allows keeping both templates.
Is there a generic function that does provide the same simplicity without generating warnings using the described options ?
If not, what is the best way to **locally** disable the issued warning ?

Comment: Hmm.  Can you add an example of how you're using this template?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: added an example for the usage

Comment: @Martin, what options are you talking about when you say "those options"?

Comment: `boost::lexical_cast<std::string>()` didn't work for you ? (It would not solve the ambiguity warning, but rolling your own "conversion" function seems superfluous)

Comment: @Matthieu: boost::lexical_cast works. I didn't know it up to now

Comment: @Rob: The conversion options generating the ambiguity, unclear formulation of mine, changed that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you'd get such a message from a scenario like this:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Y {};
struct X
{
    operator Y() const {return Y(); }
};

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, X) { return os << "X"; }
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostringstream& os, Y) { return os << "Y"; }

template<typename T> inline std::string anyToString(const T& var) {
  std::ostringstream o;
  o << var;
  return o.str();
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << anyToString(X()) << '\n';
}
```

I'd recommend using the `-pedantic` flag instead. GCC compiles it at all thanks to a compiler extension, with other compilers this will be a straight error.

---

As to your addition:

```
  template<typename T>
    T& operator<<(T& out, const SymRad& angle){
    return out << angle.deg();
  }
```

> But those have other advantages like working for several stream types.

This actually doesn't work for several stream types. E.g if `T` is `stringstream`, then `out << angle.deg();` will likely return a reference to an `ostream` which cannot be implicitly downcasted back to a `stringstream` reference.

Comment: Good example, I added the real source of evil to the description, but your example addresses just the same. -pedantic looks good on my code but I use several qt4 libraries and those are a nightmare in warning/error generation

Comment: @UncleBens: Good call on the template issue for `operator<<`, it's only compatible therefore with operators defined in a similar fashion.

Comment: @UncleBens: I thought the templated << operator would work e.g. for stringstreams and filestreams (std::ofstream and std::ostringstream). Correct me If I'm mistaken

Comment: @Martin: Try it out yourself. Existing `operator<<` for those types still returns `ostream&`. The correct way to overload `operator<<` for standard library stream is to do so for `ostream&`

Comment: @UncleBens (a bit of nitpicking): Better overload for `std::basic_ostream<Char, Traits>` than `std::ostream`: `template<typename Char, typename Traits> std::basic_ostream<Char, Traits>& operator<<(std::basic_ostream<Char, Traits>& stream, const Type& object) { }`

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler supports a #pragma for this purpose, as far as I know - I know that VC++ does. However, you could just use a boost::lexical_cast, also.

Comment: `boost::lexical_cast` fails with the same message for a similar set of overloads as demonstrated in my answer (except it uses `stringstream`).

Comment: boost::lexical cast does the trick, though I have to install and include boost for this and other people who will use the template too.